# Keep featured content post in homepage with original order

Tags: posts, query-posts, homepage, featured-post

I'm searching how to keep the featured post in my [blog homepage](http://naziman.com/) without excluding it from query post. My blog uses the Twenty Fourteen theme. I found this solution.

Open the **featured-content.php** from your theme's inc folder, and look for the following code (line 269 in our case).

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', $featured );
```

Simply comment out this line, by adding two slashes in front of it, to get this:

```
// $query->set( 'post__not_in', $featured );
```

But the file doesn't have that line and the child theme cannot override the parent theme's inc folder.

I have found [another solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/dont-exclude-featured-posts-from-front-page-query?replies=7#post-5049699) and it works, but, the problem is this code show the featured content post not in their original order. When old content post - I'm using sticky post to make featured post - become featured, the featured content post will become the first order then the other post.

I have try using conditional tag like this.

```
function show_featured_content_on_home() {
if ( !is_home() ) {
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( 'Featured_Content', 'pre_get_posts' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'show_featured_content_on_home', 31 );
```

The second page and so on okay - show the featured posts in order - but the homepage still have problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think i have the answer. To make it works, you must use the 'featured' tag than using sticky post to make featured content. So the solution is correct and i have wrong understanding and give wrong question. The conditional tag, you can remove it because the code functional without conditional tags.

Comment: I know this is pretty late but would you mind adding the above comment as an answer? This question has quite some upvotes and having a proper answer makes it more obvious. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the WPQuery

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )) ); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>   
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

and for ordering your post you can use order and orderby see reference
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query